# How to import useCombinedRefs when using react-data-grid

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

I am trying to implement the draggable columns with react-data-grid based on this example: https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/canary/stories/demos/ColumnsReordering.tsx

I see that this example requires creating a DraggableHeaderRenderer file, so I have copied the following file into my project and converted it to React: https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/canary/stories/demos/components/HeaderRenderers/DraggableHeaderRenderer.tsx

**My issue is that I do not know where to import useCombinedRefs from.** It is not exported from react-data-grid. I see in the repo that it resides in src/hooks.

I have tried the following:

```
import {useCombinedRefs} from 'react-data-grid'
// Error: Attempted import error: 'useCombinedRefs' is not exported from 'react-data-grid'.

import  {useCombinedRefs}  from 'react-data-grid/lib/hooks';
// Error: Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-data-grid/lib/hooks' in 'C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\Work\MyProject\src\ReactDataGrid'

import  useCombinedRefs  from 'react-data-grid/lib/hooks/useCombinedRefs';
// Error: Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-data-grid/lib/hooks/useCombinedRefs' in 'C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\Work\MyProject\src\ReactDataGrid'
```

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Here is my code:
**DraggableHeaderRenderer.js**

```
import { useDrag, useDrop } from 'react-dnd';
import React from 'react'

import { SortableHeaderCell } from 'react-data-grid';
import  useCombinedRefs  from 'react-data-grid/lib/hooks/useCombinedRefs';


export function DraggableHeaderRenderer({ onColumnsReorder, column, sortColumn, sortDirection, onSort }) {
  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
    item: { key: column.key, type: 'COLUMN_DRAG' },
    collect: monitor => ({
      isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging()
    })
  });

  const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: 'COLUMN_DRAG',
    drop({ key, type }) {
      if (type === 'COLUMN_DRAG') {
        onColumnsReorder(key, column.key);
      }
    },
    collect: monitor => ({
      isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
      canDrop: !!monitor.canDrop()
    })
  });

  return (
    <div
      ref={useCombinedRefs(drag, drop)}
      style={{
        opacity: isDragging ? 0.5 : 1,
        backgroundColor: isOver ? '#ececec' : 'inherit',
        cursor: 'move'
      }}
    >
      <SortableHeaderCell
        column={column}
        sortColumn={sortColumn}
        sortDirection={sortDirection}
        onSort={onSort}
      >
        {column.name}
      </SortableHeaderCell>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**TestDataGrid.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import DataGrid from 'react-data-grid';
import {DraggableHeaderRenderer} from './DraggableHeaderRenderer';
import { useState, useCallback, useMemo } from 'react';
import 'react-data-grid/dist/react-data-grid.css';

const createRows = () => {
  const rows = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 500; i++) {
    rows.push({
      id: i,
      task: `Task ${i}`,
      complete: Math.min(100, Math.round(Math.random() * 110)),
      priority: ['Critical', 'High', 'Medium', 'Low'][Math.round(Math.random() * 3)],
      issueType: ['Bug', 'Improvement', 'Epic', 'Story'][Math.round(Math.random() * 3)]
    });
  }

  return rows;
}

const createColumns = () => {
  return [
    {
      key: 'id',
      name: 'ID',
      width: 80,
    },
    {
      key: 'task',
      name: 'Title',
      resizable: true,
      sortable: true,
      draggable: true
    },
    {
      key: 'priority',
      name: 'Priority',
      resizable: true,
      sortable: true,
      draggable: true
    },
    {
      key: 'issueType',
      name: 'Issue Type',
      resizable: true,
      sortable: true,
      draggable: true
    },
    {
      key: 'complete',
      name: '% Complete',
      resizable: true,
      sortable: true,
      draggable: true
    }
  ];
}

export default function TestDataGrid() {

  const [rows] = useState(createRows)
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState(createColumns)

  const draggableColumns = useMemo(() => {
    const HeaderRenderer = (props) => {
      return <DraggableHeaderRenderer {...props} onColumnsReorder={handleColumnsReorder}/>
    }

    const handleColumnsReorder = (sourceKey, targetKey) => {
      const sourceColumnIndex = columns.findIndex(c => c.key === sourceKey);
      const targetColumnIndex = columns.findIndex(c => c.key === targetKey);
      const reorderedColumns = [...columns];

      reorderedColumns.splice(
        targetColumnIndex,
        0,
        reorderedColumns.splice(sourceColumnIndex, 1)[0]
      );

      setColumns(reorderedColumns);
    }

    return columns.map(c => {
      if(c.key === "id") return c;
      return {...c, HeaderRenderer}
    });
  }, [columns])



  return (
    <DataGrid
      columns={draggableColumns}
      rows={rows}
    />
  );
}
```